# GIS Stack Exchange 2013 Moderator Election coming soon - April 2013

Tags: discussion, election, moderators

**PROCESS STARTS 15th April 2013**

This a general (unofficial) notification that there is a GIS Stack Exchange 2013 Moderator Election coming up.

(The Stack Exchange Messaging tool was removed by the parent stack exchange hence this post)

**IMPORTANT:
There will be 2 new additional moderators to GIS Stack Exchange (as the site is active and grown since the last 2 years). So 5 in Total.**

https://gis.stackexchange.com/election/2

Nomination period begins on Apr 15 at 20:00GMT (Eastern Time US 14:00hrs)

Election begins on Apr 22 at 20:00

Election ends on Apr 30 at 20:00

Moderator candidates 6 (currently)

Moderator positions available 2

**After 7 days, the top 30 nominees, ordered by reputation, advance to the primary phase. However, if there are 10 candidates or less, we skip directly to the election phase.

Comment: Since this election is underway I have voted for this be Closed.